# Iterating $\log(x\log(x\log(...)))$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

For a real positive $x$, let $F(x)$ denote the sequence
$$
\left(\log x,\log(x\log(x)),\log(x\log(x\log(x))),\log(x\log(x\log(x\log(x)))),...\right),
$$
stopping at the first nonpositive value or infinite if it keeps staying positive.

Trivially $F(x)=(\log x)$ for $x\leqslant1$, and $F(e)=(1,1,1,1,...)$.

What else can be said? Is $F(x)$ finite for any $x<e$? Is it infinite for any $x\geqslant e$? Can you compute the limiting value for any infinite $F(x)$ except $F(e)$?

To illustrate the answer and comments below it, here is a plot:

[image]

The Mathematica code used to produce that plot:

```
Plot[{Labeled[-LambertW[-1/x], -W[-1/"x"]],
      Labeled[Log[x], Log["x"]],
      Labeled[Log[x Log[x]], Log["x" Log["x"]]],
      Labeled[Log[x Log[x Log[x]]], Log["x" Log["x" Log["x"]]]]
     }, {x, E, 10}]
```

Comment: see the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810582/1132763) the approach will still remain the same

Comment: @pie My question seems to be much simpler than that, no? Since what you refer to concerns $\log(x+\log(x+\log(...)))$ rather than $\log(x\log(x\log(...)))$

Comment: yes I know it is a multiplication but for $x>e$ I think this approach will still the same  i.e compare the sequence $\ln(x \ln (x \ln (x\dots)))$ with $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x \dots }}$ the last sequence is always bigger than the first one and hence the first sequence is monotone and bounded above by the limit of the second sequence which exist for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ which mean that for $x>e, f(x)=\ln(x f(x)) $

$$e^{f(x)} = x f(x)$$
$$\frac{-1}{x}=-f(x)e^{-f(x)}$$
$$f(x)=-\operatorname{W}\left( \frac{-1}{x}\right)$$
$\operatorname{W}$ denote (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: @pie This seems to get involved, I would be grateful if you could post an answer.

Comment: For example, I do not see why the limit always exists, and, if $f(x)$ is this limit, I don't see why $f(x)=\log(xf(x))$

Comment: If this is the case, i. e. $\log(xy)=y$, then I see that $-1/x=-ye^{-y}$ so that $y=-W(-1/x)$, but does the limit satisfy that equation? In fact empirically the graph of the limit as a function of $x$ seems to grow while $-W(-1/x)$ goes down?

Comment: The sequence satisfies $a_n = \log x + \log a_{n-1}$

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes it does

Comment: Oh I see now, you mean that substituting $x=e^y$ gives the sequence $y,y+\log y,y+\log(y+\log y),y+\log(y+\log(y+\log y)),...$, right? So we indeed land into the case pointed out by @pie?

Answer (score 3):

For $x>e,$ $\ln(x)>1$ then let's define the sequence $f_0(x)=x,$ $f_{n+1}(x)=\ln(xf_{n}(x)) $

to prove the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ always exist for any $x>e$ I will use monotone convergence theorem

$\boxed{\textbf{Monotone convergence theorem}:-\text{A monotone sequence of Real numbers converge if it  bounded}}$

if you want to see the proof of this theorem see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)

First, I will prove that the sequence is monotone: since $\ln(x\ln(x))> \ln(x)$ or in other words $f_2(x)> f_1(x)$ assume that $f_k(x)> f_{k+1}(x)$ then $f_{k}(x) =\ln(x f_{k-1}(x))$ and $f_{k+1}(x) =\ln(x f_{k}(x))$ and since $\ln(a)> \ln(b)$ if $a>b$ we conclude by induction that the sequence is monotone increasing i.e $f_{n+1}(x)> f_{n}(x)\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Secondly, I will prove the sequence is bounded for any $x$: since $\sqrt x > \ln(x)$ and $\sqrt a > \sqrt b $ if $a>b $, then we define the sequence $g_{0}(x) =x ,g_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{xg_n(x)}$ or in other form $g_n(x)= \displaystyle x^{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}}$ and it is obvious that $g_n(x)> f_n(x) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)=x $ so the sequence is bounded above by $x$.

By Monotone convergence theorem, the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$  exist  and lets define $\displaystyle  F(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$which mean that we can write

$$F(x)= \ln(x F(x))$$
$$e^{F(x)}= x F(x)$$
$$\frac{-1}{x}= -F(x)e^{-F(x)}$$
$$F(x)= -\operatorname{W}_{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{x}\right)$$

where $\operatorname{W}$ denotes [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

as @Gary pointed out in the comments referring to [4.13.11
,](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13) in NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions $W_{−1}$
is the unique branch of $W$ that stays real between $−\frac{1}{e}$
and $0$ and monotonely decreases ز

Comment: See my addition to the question. Maybe a non-principal branch of $W$ must be taken?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't know much about Lambert function but I know that it has 2 branches when $-1<x<0$ is the branch to use since $x<e $ you can see that here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p9okljiynb

Comment: In fact, looking at [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4814177/214353) at that question you linked, it seems that the correct solution must be $\log(x)-W_{-1}(-1/x)$, could you have a look?

Comment: Based on the asymptotics [$(4.13.11)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E11), the solution is $-W_{\pm 1}(-1/x\mp 0\mathrm{i})$. Note that $-W_0(-1/x) \sim 1/x$ for large positive $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე anyway f(x) is the largest solution for $f(x)=\ln(xf(x))$

Comment: @Gary Thanks! Judging by the plot, indeed $-W_{-1}(-1/x)$ fits the bill

Comment: Sorry that's me again - it is not true that only $W_{-1}$ stays real in that interval: $W_0$ is real there too. $W_0$ is excluded by another reason. What is true is that $W_{-1}$ is the unique branch that both stays real *and* monotonely decreases there (so that $-W_{-1}(-1/x)$ monotonely increases between $e$ and $\infty$).